# How to get down-level logon name from UserPrincipal in .Net

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have the following search query where I use a *User Principal Name* identification:

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, "user1@domain1.local"); //the searched UPN will be dynamic!
```

After I get the `UserPrincipal` object, I have to create a **down-level logon** format (*domain1\user1*).

Unfortunately I have the following distinguished name:

> CN=User One,OU=Every employee,DC=domain1,DC=local

It looks like `user.Context.Name` is null which is claimed to be the name of the domain. 
Also, if the selected user is a local one, I should get the *machine1\localuser1* value.

The `SamAccountName` contains *only* the user name, without the context (*user1*).

What is the best way to get that format from any `UserPrincipal` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The down-level logon format can be obtained via an `NTAccount` object. However, it requires some translation to convert the `Principal`'s *SID* to an `NTAccount`:

```
string downLevelLogonName =
       userPrincipal.Sid.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```

Using that code works in both case (domain or local computer users).

Comment: How can I get SAM account name of a cached domain user when domain is offline using his UPN name in VC++ or C#? @Nestor

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this for machine accounts, then your answer is the way to go.

But another way, strictly for Active Directory (in case it comes in handy some other time), is to look at the [`msDS-PrincipalName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/808ac90e-e80d-4ce4-ad24-cb462dd06820) attribute, which you can get via the underlying `DirectoryEntry` object:

```cs
var de = (DirectoryEntry) user.GetUnderlyingObject();
de.RefreshCache(new [] { "msDS-PrincipalName" }); //retrieve it from AD

var domainUsername = de.Properties["msDS-PrincipalName"].Value;
```

Since it's a constructed attribute, it's not returned unless you specifically ask for it, which is what you use [`RefreshCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.refreshcache#System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry_RefreshCache_System_String___) for.